# (Go) Modify websocket body in reverse proxy

Tags: go, websocket, reverse-proxy

### Hello Everyone, I'm new to Go.

I'm creating a reverse proxy server using Go.
My Server has websocket. I finally get it connected.

Now I want to change websocket message body.

Sorry If my code is weird to you. Forgive me, I'm new to Go

I'm wraping resp.body to NewReadWriteBody() in which contains wrapper for Read, Write and Closer. And I'm modifying message body inside it.

Here is how I'm doing with it:

```golang
package rever

// https://blog.joshsoftware.com/2021/05/25/simple-and-powerful-reverseproxy-in-go/
// https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/http/httputil/reverseproxy.go

import (
    "bytes"
    "crypto/tls"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
    "net/url"
    "strconv"
)

type ReadWriteBody struct {
    originBody io.ReadWriteCloser
}

func NewReadWriteBody(body io.ReadCloser) *ReadWriteBody {
    b := &ReadWriteBody{}

    rw, ok := body.(io.ReadWriteCloser)
    if !ok {
        log.Println("29: error while casting body to ReadWriteCloser")
    }
    b.originBody = rw

    return b
}

func (b *ReadWriteBody) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    buf := make([]byte, len(p)) 

    n, err = b.originBody.Read(buf)

    if err != nil {
        log.Println("43: ", err.Error())
        return n, err
    }

    buf = bytes.ReplaceAll(buf, []byte("mm.remote"), []byte("mm.local"))

    copy(p[:], buf)
    return len(p), nil
}

func (b *ReadWriteBody) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    buf := make([]byte, len(p))
    n, err = b.originBody.Write(buf)

    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err.Error())
        return n, err
    }

    buf = bytes.ReplaceAll(buf, []byte("mm.local"), []byte("mm.remote"))

    copy(p[:], buf)
    return len(p), nil
}

func (b *ReadWriteBody) Close() error {

    return b.originBody.Close()
}

type transport struct {
    http.RoundTripper
}

func (t *transport) RoundTrip(req *http.Request) (resp *http.Response, err error) {

    resp, err = t.RoundTripper.RoundTrip(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("99: ", err.Error())
        return nil, err
    }

    if resp.StatusCode == http.StatusSwitchingProtocols {

        resp.Body = NewReadWriteBody(resp.Body)

        return resp, nil
    }

    b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("114: ", err.Error())
        return nil, err
    }
    err = resp.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("119", err.Error())
        return nil, err
    }

    b = bytes.ReplaceAll(b, []byte("mm.remote"), []byte("mm.local"))


    body := ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewReader(b))
    resp.Body = body
    resp.ContentLength = int64(len(b))
    resp.Header.Set("Content-Length", strconv.Itoa(len(b)))

    return resp, nil
}

var _ http.RoundTripper = &transport{}

// NewProxy takes target host and creates a reverse proxy
func NewProxy(targetHost string) (*httputil.ReverseProxy, error) {
    url, err := url.Parse(targetHost)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("141: ", err.Error())
        return nil, err
    }

    proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(url)

    originalDirector := proxy.Director
    proxy.Director = func(req *http.Request) {
        originalDirector(req)
        modifyRequest(req)
    }

    proxy.ErrorHandler = errorHandler()

    dt := http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).Clone()
    dt.TLSClientConfig = &tls.Config{}
    dt.ForceAttemptHTTP2 = false
    proxy.Transport = &transport{dt}

    return proxy, nil
}

func modifyRequest(req *http.Request) {
    req.Host = "mm.remote"
    req.Header.Set("Accept-Encoding", "identity")
}

func errorHandler() func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request, error) {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request, err error) {
        // fmt.Printf("Got error while modifying response: %v \n", err)
    }
}


// ProxyRequestHandler handles the http request using proxy
func ProxyRequestHandler(proxy *httputil.ReverseProxy) func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        proxy.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    }
}

func Main() {
    // initialize a reverse proxy and pass the actual backend server url here
    proxy, err := NewProxy("https://mm.remote")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err.Error())
        panic(err)
    }

    // handle all requests to your server using the proxy
    http.HandleFunc("/", ProxyRequestHandler(proxy))
    fmt.Println("Server started")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8008", nil))
}
```

Comment: I noticed some problems with code.  There may be others. (1) The replacements change the websocket frame length, but there's no code to update the frame header.  (2) The code incorrectly assumes that the strings do not span calls to Read or Write (3) The code does not account for websocket frame masking in the client to server direction.

Comment: @RedBlue Thanks for answering. I do notice (1) and (3). Can you please explain more about (2)nd problem?

Comment: The target string can start in one call to Read or Write and end in the next call.  The string is in the stream, but a search in each call will not find it.

Comment: @RedBlue Thanks you so much. About (1), Can you please give me some hint to how to do it?

Comment: The easiest approach is to use a websocket package to read messages from on connection, translate the string and write the message to the other connection.